# Question with solution in question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is a fairly well received question: [Calculate $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \times \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} \times \ldots $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081519/calculate-sqrt-frac12-times-sqrt-frac12-frac12-sqrt-frac)

This question was asked again today; [deleted by author](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549625/value-of-sqrt-frac12-cdot-sqrt-frac12-frac12-cdot-sqrt-frac1)

an attempt to mark duplicate failed since the other question doesn't have a solution, though the question body itself contains a proof.

I would recommend converting the proof in the question to an answer; but that may discourage people from finding other solutions to the question; as requested by the OP. What can be done?

**Edit**: I don't know if this should be posted as an answer:

In case of converting solution in question to answer; I am ready to launch a bounty of 100 (or more if I get any more rep meanwhile such that 250 will be left for me) for another solution to the question. But I feel it inappropriate to do all these on someone else's question; unless I get a nod from community!

Comment: "that may discourage people from finding other solutions to the question" It shouldn't... A good question should generate at least 2-3 answers, in general. It's even a criterion on Area51 to determine the viability of a new site. The problem is with some people in the "fastest gun in the west crowd" who want to answer ASAP to get 1-2 upvotes quickly -- if there's already a good answer they can't get away with posting a one-line hint. So IMO, "What can be done": convert the answer into, well, an answer, maybe as CW if OP doesn't want to do it.

Comment: In the meantime the alleged duplicate was closed and subsequently deleted by the OP.

Comment: @Asaf downvotes and closed and he found the solution somewhere else=hide it from low-rep users' eyes aka delete! (I believe users above a certain rep cap can see it?)

Comment: Considering the long silence; and favourable first comment; I took the freedom to do what I proposed in question edit above.